# EPPlus importing Excel data should be Int

Tags: c#, datatable, epplus

I am using EPPlus to import data from an Excel tab into a DataTable.  All the columns in the Excel file are set to the 'General' option.

I have a number of columns that contain an integer value (the column is still set to 'General' but all the values are integer-like, i.e. 1, 2, 3, etc.) but when I import to a DataTable I get values like 1.00, 2.00, 3.00, etc.

Is there a reason why EPPlus is adding the decimal points and/or how do I prevent this?

This is the block of code that does the import:

```
    int startRow = headerRow + 1;
    ExcelRange wsRow;
    DataRow dr;

    // if headerRow exists (headerRow > 0) then add columns with names
    foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[headerRow, 1, headerRow, totalCols])
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(headerRow > 0 ? firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
    }


    for (int rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= totalRows; rowNum++)
    {
        wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, totalCols];
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        foreach (var cell in wsRow)
        {
            dr[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
        }

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try setting the column datatype in your DataTable to Int32? `dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(Int32))` Or when you add it to your DataRow, convert it to Int32. `dr[cell.Start.Column - 1] = Convert.ToInt32(cell.Text)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is excel stores all numeric numbers as doubles and then just applies formatting.  So 1.0 when the format is set to "General" will shows as 1 because excel removes the trailing .0 as its "interpretation".

Are you sure you are using `cell.Text`?  Or are you actually using `cell.Value` which would explain what you are seeing.  If they are truly numbers in excel (not numbers store as text) then `.Text` will return a string (e.g. "1") representation of `.Value` (e.g. 1.0 which is how 1 would be stored) after excel has applied its styling of "General".

So, if you are confident it will always be an int, you could simple take the .Value and cast to an int or .Text and parse.  If you are not so confident, then you will have to test each value as you loop and look for a lack of a modulus.